# save in userdefaults is crashing app

Tags: swift, save, nsuserdefaults, swift4

I am new to swift and trying to save array into userdefaults and my app is crashing.

I am using below code

```
let currentObject = productsArray[clickedPosition] as Product
print("currentObject===\(currentObject)")
var currentCartArray = [Product]()
currentCartArray.append(currentObject)

UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCartArray, forKey: "Wafaa_MyCart")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Below is what I get in output

```
currentObject===Product(Id: Optional(10007), TitleEN: Optional("PDF 1"), 
                TitleAR: Optional("PDF 1 AR"), DescriptionEN: nil, 
                DescriptionAR: nil, AboutEN: Optional("Merchant 1"), 
                AboutAR: Optional("Merchant 1"), CategoryId: Optional(1), 
                UnitSold: Optional(0), CategoryEN: Optional("Category 1"), 
                CategoryAR: Optional("الفئة الأولى"), CountryId: Optional(23), 
                CountryEN: Optional("Egypt"), CountryAR: Optional("مصر"), 
                CountryFlag: Optional("http://xxxx.xxxxx.info//Files/CountryPhotos/EG-128.png"),
                 MerchantId: Optional(1), MerchantNameEN: Optional("Merchant 1"), 
                MerchantNameAR: Optional("Merchant 1"), Logo: Optional(""), 
                CurrencyId: Optional(1), CurrencyCode: Optional(414), 
                CurrencyEN: Optional("Kuwaiti Dinar"), CurrencyAR: Optional("دينار كويتى"), 
                SymbolEN: Optional("KWD"), SymbolAR: Optional("KWD"), 
                Discount: Optional("0%"), 
                FinalPrice: Optional("1.000"), Price: Optional("1.000"), 
                OverViewAR: Optional("ddddddd"), OverViewEN: Optional("dddd"), 
                NoUsersRate: Optional(0), IsFavorite: Optional(false), 
                IsPurchased: Optional(false), 
                FavoriteIds: nil, Rate: Optional(3), 
                DemoVideo: Optional("http://player.vimeo.com/video/1111"), 
                VideoDuration: Optional("06:12:00"), ViewersCount: Optional(7), 
                Photo: Optional("http://xxxx.xxxx.info//Images/noimageicon.png"), 
                AddedOnDate: Optional("28/02/2018 01:43 PM"))
```

this crash saying below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
"Wafaa.Product(Id: Optional(10007), TitleEN: Optional(\"PDF 1\"), 
    TitleAR: Optional(\"PDF 1 AR\"), DescriptionEN: nil, DescriptionAR: nil, 
    AboutEN: Optional(\"Merchant 1\"), AboutAR: Optional(\"Merchant 1\"), 
    CategoryId: Optional(1), UnitSold: Optional(0), CategoryEN: Optional(\"Category 1\"), 
    CategoryAR: Optional(\"\U0627\U0644\U0641\U0626\U0629 \U0627\U0644\U0623\U0648\U0644\U0649\"), 
    CountryId: Optional(23), CountryEN: Optional(\"Egypt\"), 
    CountryAR: Optional(\"\U0645\U0635\U0631\"), 
    CountryFlag: Optional(\"http://xxx.xxxx.info//Files/CountryPhotos/EG-128.png\"), 
    MerchantId: Optional(1), MerchantNameEN: Optional(\"Merchant 1\"), 
    MerchantNameAR: Optional(\"Merchant 1\"), Logo: Optional(\"\"), 
    CurrencyId: Optional(1), CurrencyCode: Optional(414), 
    CurrencyEN: Optional(\"Kuwaiti Dinar\"), 
    CurrencyAR: Optional(\"\U062f\U064a\U0646\U0627\U0631 \U0643\U0648\U064a\U062a\U0649\"), 
    SymbolEN: Optional(\"KWD\"), SymbolAR: Optional(\"KWD\"), 
    Discount: Optional(\"0%\"), FinalPrice: Optional(\"1.000\"), 
    Price: Optional(\"1.000\"), OverViewAR: Optional(\"ddddddd\"), 
    OverViewEN: Optional(\"dddd\"), NoUsersRate: Optional(0), 
    IsFavorite: Optional(false), IsPurchased: Optional(false), 
    FavoriteIds: nil, Rate: Optional(3), 
    DemoVideo: Optional(\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxx\"), VideoDuration: Optional(\"06:12:00\"), 
    ViewersCount: Optional(7), Photo: Optional(\"http://xxxx.xxxx.info//Images/noimageicon.png\"), 
    AddedOnDate: Optional(\"28/02/2018 01:43 PM\"))"
```

I remember, in Objective-C it used to crash only if I have NULL, but here I don't have any null, still why crash is happening?

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: "'Attempt to insert non-property list object". I guess that `Product` is not valid. You should also make Product NSCoding compliant too.

Comment: And please don't use `.synchronize()`, it's not only useless (soft deprecated) but can lead to issues sometimes.

Comment: To clarify on what @Larme said, user defaults can only store _property lists_, which are a limited set of foundation objects (basically numbers, strings, dates, data, and collections of same). If you want to store anything else in defaults they must be converted into one of those types. See [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to serialise your object into a `Data` instance before actually storing to `UserDefaults`. Fortunately, Swift 4 provides built-in tools to easily do both serialisation and deserialisation (`Codable` protocol).

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/172145/encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4) where the required steps are described in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

Userdefaults are not meant to store objects like you are trying to do. They are meant to store Numbers, Strings, Dates, etc. Try Core Data for object type.